# Is there a way to select a specific parent using XPath?

Tags: html, xml, xpath, cypress

From the reading I've done so far I don't think it's possible but in the off chance it is, here goes:

Given the following overly simplified HTML (based on HTML generated from a CMS, so no real control over it)

```
<div class="random">
  <div class="random"> <-- This is the one I want
    <div class="random">
      <div class="random">
        <span class="random">
          <input id="experiment-randomnumbers-textinput-2">
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have hacked together the following XPath expression to get the node that I want:

```
//input[contains(@id,'experiments') and contains(@id,'textinput-2')]/parent::span/parent::div/parent::div/parent::div
```

The question is, is there a neater way of doing this? I'm assuming it can't be done in CSS?

Cheers

Rob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let `BASE_XPATH` = `//input[contains(@id,'experiments') and contains(@id,'textinput-2')]`.

Then, if the target is four ancestors up, and you don't care about the ancestor elements' names:

```
BASE_XPATH/../../../..
```

If there's a unique condition (in elided parts of your markup) among ancestors:

```
BASE_XPATH/ancestor::*[ UNIQUE_PREDICATE ]
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the prompt reply.  Much more readable.  Unfortunately I can't see anything unique anywhere useful in the DOM as the vast majority of it is automatically generated.  Being able to use `/../` is quite useful though :)

Comment: You can also do `ancestor::div[4]` which works its way up the tree to find the fourth ancestor named `div`.